# Video Compression of

Tags: video, mp4, video-capture, video-processing

When filming videos, somehow the files always take way to much memory.
All the tips I read on the internet are about reduzing the resolution, which is a complete useless tip.

Like a 2min 30sec video takes like 230mb, while normal movies take 750mb and are about 90min long.
They have the SAME resolution(1280x720) but somehow only need 8mb per minute instead of 92mb per minute when filming on my phone.
I have an android phone and the videos are saved in mp4.

So how can I compress the videos to take up a a more reasonable memory space?
Any existing app, or framework with whom I could build my own compressor?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the bitrate of the compressed video. More aggressive compression will use a lower bitrate and result in a substantially smaller file. You can change the image quality setting in the video recorder app to encode at a lower bitrate. This will not affect the resolution or frame rate, but rather the quality of each compressed image. You could also lower the frame rate from the typical value of 30 to the US cinema standard of 24 fps.

See here for the bitrates used by various video streaming services: https://toolstud.io/video/filesize.php